# How to decode EXI file (Efficient XML AgileDelta) without the Tag <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

Tags: exi

I tried to encode nd decode HTML file with Efficient XML. How do I prevent from the decoder to add the tag  in the begining of the result file ?
Here is the code i am using:

```
        EFXFactory factory = EFXFactory.newInstance();
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(exiFileName);
        FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(encodedFileName);
        Transcoder trans = factory.newTranscoder();
        trans.encode(input, output);
```

I tried to change some properties of the factoy but it didn't help. for example:

```
        factory.setProperty(EFXProperty.HEADER, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to contact AgileDelta for support because the API is product-specific and is not published.

Having that said, if the API supports SAX, then you can use JAXP TransformerHandler to convert SAX events into XML with or without XML declaration at the front.